# Convert varchar to varbinary in vba

Tags: sql, excel

Im trying to convert varchar to varbinary through vba code while trying to insert data from excel to sql database table

```
sqlstring = ""
sqlstring = sqlstring & " Insert into tblbindetails (filename,fildata) "
sqlstring = sqlstring & "values( '" & ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Lead sheet").Range("I2") & "'," & Convert(varbinary(Max), ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Lead sheet").Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select) & ")"
```

fildata is defined as varbinary(max)

**I need to convert ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Lead sheet").Range("E1").End(xlDown).Select into varbinary.**

I get this **error** on cn.Execute 
-2147217900, Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Your help would be appreciated.
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: remove the `.Select`

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Have you tried using the `CONVERT` function to *convert* to `varbinary(max)` like the error message is saying?

Comment: What is varbinary(max) in vba? I get error sub or function not defined

Comment: This isn't about VBA, it's about the SQL statement. VBA isn't complaining, SQL Server is. You need `values('1', CONVERT('" & ... & ...`

Comment: That said I'm surprised your VBA code even runs up to that point, because `Range.Select` doesn't return anything and it wouldn't be caught at compile-time because of all these late-bound chained member calls... but *should* blow up at run-time as you build this SQL string -- make sure you don't have `On Error Resume Next` hiding any errors here.

Comment: **I have updated the query** but it gives me error on varbinary. error says sub or function not defined